# unable to install nex/yii2-chosen extension

Tags: yii2, jquery-chosen

I am unable to install nex/yii2-chosen extension in my project using composer please.

My composer shows :

> C:\xampp\htdocs\labplus>composer require nex/yii2-chosen Deprecation
>   Notice: The Composer\Package\LinkConstraint\MultiConstraint class is 
>   deprecated, use Composer\Semver\Constraint\MultiConstraint instead. in
>   phar://C
>   :/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Package/LinkConstrain
>   t/MultiConstraint.php:17 Deprecation Notice: The
>   Composer\Package\LinkConstraint\LinkConstraintInterface interface is
>   deprecated, use Composer\Semver\Constraint\ConstraintInterface inst
>   ead. in
>   phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Packa
>   ge/LinkConstraint/LinkConstraintInterface.php:17 Failed to decode
>   response: zlib_decode(): data error Retrying with degraded mode, check
>   https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubles hooting.md#degraded-mode
>   for more info Using version dev-master for nex/yii2-chosen
>   ./composer.json has been updated Loading composer repositories with
>   package information Updating dependencies (including require-dev) Your
>   requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - The requested package dbtek/chosen-bootstrap could not be found in any ver sion, there may be a typo in the package name.   Problem 2
>       - The requested package nex/yii-chosen could not be found in any version, th ere may be a typo in the package name.
>
> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original
>   content.

[see the cmd snap for more](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxDTz.png)

Comment: show your installation command please..

Comment: composer require "nex/yii2-chosen" : "*"

Comment: You can also view in attachment. I already attached the cmd snap with the question having label is "see the cmd snap for more"

Comment: I bet you haven't installed `fxp/composer-asset-plugin` globally. Refer to this [guide page](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html#installing-via-composer).

Comment: THANXXXXXXXXXX lot Bewulfenator.. You are greate. You really helped me and saved my efforts. thanks once again